# Sequelize Object undefined, but present in previous then statement

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an issue where I am trying to access an object, but for some reason it is coming up as `undefined` despite creating the object earlier in the statement and being able to access it from a separate then statement.

Here is a better explanation of the logic of my `post` method below. On the previous route to `/sign-up/organization` a user is created. That user then creates an organization, which in the first then statement creates a record of the relationship between the user and organization in the `member` table. Right after that record is created, the user model should be updated with the organization id that was created.

**Terminal Output:**

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `organization` (`organization_id`,`organization_name`,`admin`,`discovery_source`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'Organization Test','test@testg.com','Nice','2016-01-17 19:07:21','2016-01-17 19:07:21'); 
Error at PostTypeError: Cannot read property 'organizationId' of undefined
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `member` (`member_id`,`member_email`,`organization_id`,`user_id`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'tttest@testg.com',4,4,'2016-01-17 19:07:21','2016-01-17 19:07:21');
```

Error occurs at `models.User.update`

routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var appRoutes   = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');


appRoutes.route('/sign-up/organization')

    .get(function(req, res){
        models.User.find({
            where: {
                user_id: req.user.email
            }, attributes: [ 'user_id', 'email'
            ]
        }).then(function(user){
            res.render('pages/app/sign-up-organization.hbs',{
                user: req.user
            });
        })  
    })

    .post(function(req, res, user){
        models.Organization.create({
            organizationName: req.body.organizationName,
            admin: req.body.admin,
            discoverySource: req.body.discoverySource
        }).then(function(organization, user){
            organization = organization;
            console.log(organization);
            models.Member.create({
                organizationId: organization.organizationId,
                memberEmail: req.user.email,
                userId: req.user.user_id
            },{ where: { user_id: req.user.user_id }});

        }).then(function(organization, user){
            models.User.update({
                organizationId: organization.organizationId
            });
            res.redirect('/app');
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
            console.log('Error at Post' + error);
        })
    });



appRoutes.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    console.log('User logged out');
    res.redirect('/');
});



module.exports = appRoutes;
```

page/app/sign-up-organization.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {{> head}}
</head>
<body>
    {{> navigation}}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="/app/sign-up/organization" method="post">
                <p>{{user.email}}</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="{{user.email}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="organizationId">
                <label for="sign-up-organization">Company/Organization Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sign-up-organization"  name="organizationName" value="" placeholder="Company/Organization">
                <a href="#" id="sign-up-add-discovery-source">Add Another Discovery Source</a>
                <div id="sign-up-organization-discovery-source">
                    <input type="text" id="discovery-source-field" placeholder="Discovery Source" name="discoverySource">
                </div>
                <br />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <a href="/login">Already have an account? Login here!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Organization:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {


    var Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
        organizationId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'organization_id',
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        organizationName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'organization_name'
        },
        admin: DataTypes.STRING,
        discoverySource: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'discovery_source'
        },
        members: DataTypes.STRING
    },{
        freezeTableName: true,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(db) {
                Organization.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'member', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
            },
        },
    });

        return Organization;
    }
```

**User:**

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            User.belongsToMany(db.Organization, { through: 'member', foreignKey: 'organizationId'})
        },
        generateHash: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        validPassword: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        },
    },


});
    return User;
}
```

**Member:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Member = sequelize.define('member', {
    memberId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'member_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    memberEmail: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'member_email'
    },
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'user_id',
        allowNull: true
    }
},{
    freezeTableName: true,
});

    return Member;
}
```

**db-index:**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var path = require('path');
var config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/config.js'));
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
});

var db = {}

db.Member = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/member");

db.Organization = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/organization");

db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");

db.Annotation = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/annotation");

db.User.associate(db);
db.Organization.associate(db);
db.Annotation.associate(db);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Can you show the error and highlight the block of code that produces the error? This will make it easier for one to answer your question.

Comment: sorry about that. I updated the question with the terminal output

Comment: Thank you. You may need to remove any files from the post that are not relevant to the question. It makes the question easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `Promise` object obtained from a *then* statement in another *then* statement, you need to return the `Promise` object.

You need to return the `organization` object obtained in the first 'then' call of the `post` method:

```
...
.post(function(req, res, user){
    models.Organization.create({
        organizationName: req.body.organizationName,
        admin: req.body.admin,
        discoverySource: req.body.discoverySource
    }).then(function(organization, user){
        organization = organization;
        console.log(organization);
        models.Member.create({
            organizationId: organization.organizationId,
            memberEmail: req.user.email,
            userId: req.user.user_id
        },{ where: { user_id: req.user.user_id }});
        // Return the organization Promise instance here to make it
        // available in the next then statememt
        return organization;
    }).then(function(organization, user){
        models.User.update({
            organizationId: organization.organizationId
        });
        res.redirect('/app');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
        console.log('Error at Post' + error);
    })
});
```

...